# LastWrite NotifyFilter in FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, excel, filesystemwatcher

I have written a utility to figure out when an Excel file is updated. I have to read the same Excel file once the updates are made. However I am not notified about the updates, instead a temp file creation is notified(which is of no use to me). How can I do it in C# Windows form?

Here's the code snippet used :

```
                  watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                  watcher.Filter = "*.xlsx";
                  watcher.NotifyFilter =  NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
                  watcher.Path = "G:\\Prerequisites Folder";
                  watcher.SynchronizingObject = this;
                  watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);

           void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
           {

            if (e.Name.StartsWith("~") == false)
                  btnRefreshPrequisites_Click(null, null);
            }
```

Anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

This is by design, a common approach for many programs. When modifying files, they try to make sure that those modifications don't destroy the original file if they fail for any reason.  So they copy the original file to a temporary name, make the changes to that temporary file.  And when nothing goes wrong, rename the original, rename the temporary to give it the same name as the original and finally deleted the renamed original.

So you'll need to be interested in the Renamed event as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
       {
        //no need to check if (e.Name.StartsWith("~") == false)
         // comment the if statement
        if (e.Name.StartsWith("~") == false)
              btnRefreshPrequisites_Click(null, null);

         //do your work
        }
```